How did the 'others' come to know that Walt was significant enough to merit investigation/testing?
In S1 the others come by boat to take Walter from the raft manned by Michael (Walter's father), Sawyer and Jin. How did they know Walter was special and was worth the effort/risk to obtain?

Frankly, that whole plot line was a bad kludge to get the kid off the show before he aged faster than the plot.

Often in fiction there is a 'throw-away' character or SEVERAL put in place to advance a concept. To me, I do not care... what is the point being advanced?
